# In mysql can auto execute some kind trigger or function or procedure when some rows are updated?

Tags: mysql, function, triggers, procedure

I'm new to dbs. I have this table called guide:

```
+----------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+
| phone    | address              | name         | cellphone   |
+----------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2555555  | 1020 PANORAMA        | JUAN CARLOS  | 0999999999  |
| 2555555  | GABRIEL JOSE 1020    | JOSE MIGUEL  | 0988888888  |
| 2555555  | C ATARAZANA 1020     | SILVIA       | 0777777777  |
| 2555555  | GABRIEL JOSE 1020    | VIOLETA      | 0888888888  |
+----------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

and when it gets a new added row for example

```
+----------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+
| phone    | address              | name         | cellphone   |
+----------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2555555  | 1020 PANORAMA        | JUAN CARLOS  | 0999999999  |
| 2555555  | FRANCISCO  1520      | JOSE MIGUEL  | 0988888888  |
| 2555555  | C ATARAZANA 1020     | SILVIA       | 0777777777  |
| 2555555  | GABRIEL JOSE 1020    | VIOLETA      | 0888888888  |
|          | GABRIEL VILLA 102    | PANCHA       |             | NEW DATA
+----------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

it add in other table called names only the names and the cell phone

```
+--------------+-------------+
| name         | cellphone   |
+--------------+-------------+
| JUAN CARLOS  | 0999999999  |
| JOSE MIGUEL  | 0988888888  |
| SILVIA       | 0777777777  |
| VIOLETA      | 0888888888  |
| PANCHA       |             | NEW DATA
+--------------+-------------+
```

and when the row in the first table its updated it update the second one 
its possible something of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Trigger

```
`CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `dbname`.`guideafterinsert` 
AFTER INSERT ON `guide` 
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    update phone 
    set
    name  = new.name,
    cellphone=new.cellphone,
    END`
```